# JQuery Drag N Drop Issue Between Containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Ok i'm having an issue here where I have draggables and droppables
the weird thing is that once I drop it on a container I have
to recreate the draggable to move it back.

Basically I have the origin

```
$("#mykeys ul li").draggable({
revert:"invalid",
helper: "clone",
cursor: 'move'});
```

then i have the droppable block. The issue im having is
how to get the actual droppable blocks to drag n drop
between eachother.

SO Basiclly I can drag n drop from the origin to the class containers
but i cant drag n drop between the class containers

Do I need to use sortables?

Here is the JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rmatakajr/FN7Xx

Thank for your help

Comment: Try `$(ui.draggable).appendTo(this);`

Comment: Awesome man! However that's not the main issue, its definitely more elegant tho. The issue i'm having trying to figure out is how to move between the droppable in a sort type fashion.

Comment: So say i moved all the draggables to the droppables. How would I do a sortable between all the droppables? Thats what im banging my head on right now

Comment: see the update below.... the accept criteria is changed

Comment: You are aweomse man! Thanks for that! BTW is there any way to make that sortable so that the list items dont over write each other?

Comment: Hey I have been at this for like 4 hours.. I tried cloning and replaceWith to try to swap the containers objects out when dropped on and im just hitting a brick wall here.. I would like to make a sortable effect so the objects swap between the containers - this way the items are not over written - i just cant figure it out hoping someone can enligten me hhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(".drop-container").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
    accept: "#mykeys ul li, .drop-container li",
    //connectWith: ".drop-container",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).empty();
        $(ui.draggable).appendTo(this);
    },
    out: function (event, ui) {
        console.log('dragged out');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XQ6yw/)